# Compare string contents, regardless of character order

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am doing an assignment and I have gotten pretty far!
The assignment is to make an anagram program that takes an input of a 4-letter word, and outputs all anagrams of that word's letters.

For example, the word 'rats' would output: rats, rat, at, tar, tars, star, sat, etc.

I have gotten far enough that my program will output every anagram, as long as the letters of the output word match the order of the input word.

For example, the word 'rats' only outputs: rats, rat, and at.

I have a feeling that my experience with Python is tainting my thinking here, as I am really only using a couple loops. It works fine, but I am missing that last piece.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

echo "I installed wamerican for an american english dictionary, as linux.words wasn't present on my system."

input=$1

dictionary=$(cat /etc/dictionaries-common/words)
count="0"

if [[ -z "$input" || ${#input} -gt 4 ]];
then
        echo "Usage: anagram.sh <word to anagram, 4 characters or less>"

elif [[ -n "$input" &&  ${#input} -le 4 ]];
then

        for line in $dictionary;
        do
                if [[ ${input[@]} =~ ${line[@]} && ${#line} -ge 2 ]];
                then
                        echo $line
                fi
        done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your direct question is fairly straight forward in bash. If you know the length of `input` will be 4-letters, you can simply use the *parameter expansion* for string indexing and 4 loops to permute the letters in `input`. For example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

input=${1:-rats}

[ "${#input}" -eq 4 ] || {  # validate input is 4 characters
  printf "error: input not 4 characters.\n" >&2
  exit 1
}

# loop over each char
for ((i = 0; i < ${#input}; i++)); do
  # loop over each char not index $i
  for ((j = 0; j < ${#input}; j++)); do
    [ "$j" = "$i" ] && continue
      # loop over each char not index $i or $j
      for ((k = 0; k < ${#input}; k++)); do
        [ "$k" = "$i" ] || [ "$k" = "$j" ] && continue
          # loop over last char (not index $i, $j or $k)
          for ((l = 0; l < ${#input}; l++)); do
            [ "$l" = "$i" ] || [ "$l" = "$j" ] || [ "$l" = "$k" ] && continue
            # add word formed by indexes to words array
            words+=("${input:$i:1}${input:$j:1}${input:$k:1}${input:$l:1}")
          done
      done
  done
done

for i in "${words[@]}"; do    # loop over words in array
  printf "%s\n" "$i"
done
```

Above the loops are used to derive the 26 unique permutations of the 4-letter word (6 beginning with each letter) and each unique permutation is captured in the array `words` for later use by your script.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash rats.sh
rats
rast
rtas
rtsa
rsat
rsta
arts
arst
atrs
atsr
asrt
astr
tras
trsa
tars
tasr
tsra
tsar
srat
srta
sart
satr
stra
star
```

However, the remainder of your script needs help.

```sh
dictionary=$(cat /etc/dictionaries-common/words)
```

Aside from commiting a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use of `cat`*, also stated as *Useless Use of `cat`*) See [Useless Use of Cat](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), you are using a *command substitution* to assign the entire contents of `/etc/dictionaries-common/words` to the variable `dictionary`.

That is wildly inefficient and not what variables were intended for. When you have thousands of lines of input, you need to either `mapfile` (synonymous with `readarray`) to map the input to elements of an array, OR you need to rethink how you want to access that many items.

Here, it seems that looping over the permutations and using `grep` to compare a permutation or substring against the content of `/etc/dictionaries-common/words` would be a far better way to determining if each unique permutation (or substring thereof) can be found as a whole word in the file (see the `-w`, `--word-regexp` option to `grep`)

Additionally, `input` is a string, not an array in bash, so `${input[@]}` isn't what you want. Simply `$input` (unqoted in `[[ .. ]]`) will suffice. Your use of `${line[@]}` also falls victim to the same syntax mix-up.

Hopefully this will suggest a different direction to take. Let me know if you have further questions.